# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dynamodb.DefaultSource when trying to read from DynamoDB using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to read data from DynamoDB using Apache Spark and Java.
Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

    // Building the Spark session
    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = SparkConfiguration.buildSparkContext();
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(sparkContext.sc()).getOrCreate();

    // Building a dataset of the Covid19Citation table
    Dataset citations = sparkSession.read()
        .option("tableName", "Covid19Citation")
        .option("aws.dynamodb.region", "us-east-1")
        .option("aws.dynamodb.endpoint", "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
        .format("dynamodb").load();
    citations.show(10);
    LOGGER.info("Citations count: " + citations.count());
    

}
```

And here is `build.gradle` file:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.audienceproject/spark-dynamodb
    compile group: 'com.audienceproject', name: 'spark-dynamodb_2.12', version: '1.1.2'


    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '2.4.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: '2.4.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version: '3.0.0'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    zip64 true
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.lcarvalho.sparkddb.Covid19CitationsWordCount'
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Spark Job', 'Implementation-Version': version
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
    }
    baseName = 'Covid19CitationsWordCount'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

Every time I run this code I'm getting exception below ( I tried to run this job locally and on AWS, and I getting same exception) :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: dynamodb. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.dataSourceNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:647)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:697)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
        at com.lcarvalho.sparkddb.Covid19CitationsWordCount.main(Covid19CitationsWordCount.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dynamodb.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:633)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:633)
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:633)
        ... 16 more
```

I have no idea what is happening here.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I finally found the solution.

Seems like dynamodb connector is not being available on the worker. One way to fix this is to send JARs to the nodes in the cluster and making them available in the classpath of all executors.

This can be achived by creating S3 bucket where the `spark-dynamodb_2.12-1.1.2` jar will be stored and then specifying `--jars` option to `spark-submit`

Since EMR can access S3 like a filesystem we can pass the S3 path itself in the `--jars` option.

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --jars s3://my-bucket/my-jars/spark-dynamodb_2.12-1.1.2 ...
```

Other solution, is to pass following argument to `.format` function:

```
.format("com.audienceproject.spark.dynamodb.datasource.DefaultSource")
```